# Landsat-8 level 2 DN to reflectance

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat-8, digital-image-processing, land-cover, land-classification

I have downloaded a series of Landsat-8 **level 2** images. My main purpose is to obtain reflectance out of them; however, the scale of the different bands does not look like reflectance (e.g. Blue Band goes from -2000 to 9393).

I am assuming those numbers correspond to digital numbers (DN) (I am not 100% sure), so I am wondering if there is a procedure to convert this DN to reflectance for this **level 2** data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a scaling factor applied to the data. See the surface reflectance table at  https://www.usgs.gov/land-resources/nli/landsat/landsat-collection-2-level-2-science-products.